# jQuery update div with value of input onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a mini calculator which involves changing input values, doing a little bit of addition etc then updating div's with the value of the inputs.

```
$('.skillcount').change(function() {
   var value = parseFloat($(this).val()) / 2;
   alert(value);
   $(".missed").append('value');
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5De46/65/

```js
$('.skillcount').change(function() {
  var value = parseFloat($(this).val()) / 2;
  alert(value);
  $(".missed").append('value');
});

// value from span .missed + 1498
$('.missed').change(function() {
  var value = parseFloat($(this).val()) + 1498;
  alert(value);
  $(".cost").append('value');
});

// value from skillcount - value from '.cost'
$('.skillcount').change(function() {
  var value = parseFloat($(this).val()) - $('.cost');
  alert(value);
  $(".remaining").append('value');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- enter an amount - default 1000 -->
<input type="text" class="skillcount" name="skillcount" value="1000" />

<p>
  <!-- that ammount from skillcount divided by 2 and added into '.missed' -->
  Missed: £
  <span class="missed"></span>
</p>

<p>
  <!-- Take output value of the paragraph '.missed' and + 1498 to it -->
  True Cost: £
  <span class="cost"></span>
</p>

<p>
  <!-- Value of skillcount 'minus' value of the paragraph '.cost' -->
  Remaining: £
  <span class="remaining"></span>
</p>
```

I have put all comments and explanations in the fiddle in more detail. I just don't know how to take the values from the output and place them into the paragraph then use the values to do more basic calculations.

Comment: You need to have a [mcve] in your question, not on a fiddle

Comment: so many changes are not required as it is starting a chain reaction and hence wrong calculation....do all manipulation in one **.change()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for simple reason..you have put string quotes on the 'value'

```
var value = parseFloat($(this).val()) * 2;
  alert(value);
  $(".missed").text('value');
```

which should have been

```
var value = parseFloat($(this).val()) / 2;
  alert(value);
  $(".missed").text(value);
```

also ..you cannot append() what it not html..to change you have to .text()

**Secondly** you are too liberal with $(this)...which is blank inside $('.missed') function & subsequent because the original value for skillcount has changed ... Also there are a lot of change chains which are not required..

```
$('.skillcount').change(function() {
   var skillcount= $(".skillcount").val();

    var missed= parseFloat(skillcount) * 2;         
    $(".missed").text(missed);

    var costValue = parseFloat(missed) + 1498;    
    $(".cost").text(costValue);

     var diffValue = parseFloat(skillcount) - costValue;     
    $(".remaining").text(diffValue);
});
```

I have updated the jsfiddle...could you have a look'

http://jsfiddle.net/6as9gef0/7/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
onSkillCountChange()

$('.skillcount').keyup(function() {
     onSkillCountChange()
});
 
 function onSkillCountChange(){
   var originalvalue = $(".skillcount").val();
   
    var value = parseFloat(originalvalue) * 2;
     
    $(".missed").text(value);
    
    var costValue = parseFloat(value) + 1498;    
    $(".cost").text(costValue);
    
     var diffValue = parseFloat(costValue) - originalvalue;     
    $(".remaining").text(diffValue);
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- enter an amount - default 1000 -->
<input type="text" class="skillcount" name="skillcount" value="1000"/>

<p>
<!-- that ammount from skillcount divided by 2 and added into '.missed' -->
Missed: £
<span class="missed"></span>
</p>

<p>
<!-- Take output value of the paragraph '.missed' and + 1498 to it -->
True Cost: £
<span class="cost"></span>
</p>

<p>
<!-- Value of skillcount 'minus' value of the paragraph '.cost' -->
Remaining: £
<span class="remaining"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working for the first bit dividing by 2. Doesn't seem to work it out as i type or even divide the default value? Sorry, I am a newbie to this!

Comment: Hi, yes ive just worked it all out and its great the only one i changed was the /2 it should have been *2 instead. The only thing that would be great would be if it could work out the default value as you come to the page and also as you type it changes the values? Thank you very much for your help! Really appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, if skillcount is 1000, missed should be 2000. http://jsfiddle.net/6as9gef0/4/ other figures look good

Comment: Great, thanks, would it work updating the values as you type, like keychange, you so see it instantly?

Comment: It will work if we add a **.keyup()** event....check this updated jsfiddle sir .. http://jsfiddle.net/6as9gef0/7/

Comment: just a quick one, is there any way of getting a comma between the numbers if its like 1,000 or 100,000 at all?

Comment: parseFloat is convert the string to number.. anyvalue that doesnt go inside parseFloat will have the comma if at all

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.

In the line:

```
$(".missed").append('value');
```

remove the quotes from around 'value'. You are appending a string here instead of the variable.

```
$(".missed").text(value);
```

you can also use .html(value)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to change inmediatly, i recommend change .on('change',..) to .on('input',..). (If you want to change on "submit", write .on('change,..)

In other hand, change .append to .text.

Sample code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script text="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('ready',function(){
         $('.skillcount').on('input',function() {
             var valueMissed = parseFloat($(this).val()) / 2;
             alert(valueMissed );
             $(".missed").text(valueMissed);

             var valueCost = valueMissed + 1498;
            alert(valueCost );
            $(".cost").append(valueCost);

            var valueRemaining = parseFloat($(this).val()) - valueCost 
            alert(valueRemaining );
            $(".remaining").append(valueRemaining );
    });
    </script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- enter an amount - default 1000 -->
    <input type="text" class="skillcount" name="skillcount" value="1000" />

    <p>
      <!-- that ammount from skillcount divided by 2 and added into '.missed' -->
      Missed: £
      <span class="missed"></span>
    </p>

    <p>
      <!-- Take output value of the paragraph '.missed' and + 1498 to it -->
      True Cost: £
      <span class="cost"></span>
    </p>

    <p>
      <!-- Value of skillcount 'minus' value of the paragraph '.cost' -->
      Remaining: £
      <span class="remaining"></span>
    </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```